# Issue in the servlet container, getting the servlet location twice

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am learning JSP/Servet and try to make a simple Servlet controller.

This is my project stucture:

[image]

test is the homepage, user can enter his/her hobbies. Confirm page, will confirm the details to user. It has the option to go back and edit the information or submit the information to process.jsp page.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FirstController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ch2.servletController.Controller</servlet-class>         
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FirstController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ch2/servletController/Controller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eu">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Simple web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    This is a simple HTML page that has a form in it.
        <form action="ch2/servletController/Controller">
        <p>
            Hobby:<input type="text" name="hobby" value="${param.hobby}">
            <input type="submit" name ="confirmButton" value="confirm">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Confirm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Confirm Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        The value of the hobby that was sent to this page is <strong>${param.hobby} </strong>.
    <p>
    <form action="ch2/servletController/Controller">
    <p>
        If there is any error, please click the edit button and 
            to process press the Submit button <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="hobby" value="${param.hobby}">
        <input type="submit" name="editButton" value="Edit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Process.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Process Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Thank you for your information, Your hobby of <strong>${param.hobby} </strong> will
    be added to our records, eventually.
    </body>
    </html>
```

Controller.java

```
package ch2.servletController;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String address;
        if(request.getParameter("submit") != null)
        {
            address = "Process.jsp";
        }
        else if ( request.getParameter("editButton") != null)
        {
            address = "test.jsp";
        }
        else
        {
            address = "/Confirm.jsp";
        }

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
                request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
        dispatcher.forward ( request, response);
    }
}
```

test.jsp output: 
[image]

Click confirm:
[image]

However I am not able to go back to test.jsp page and Process.jsp page:

This is the error which I am getting when I click on edit button of the confirm.jsp page.
[image]

As I can notice I am not the the correct path and even servlet location is repeating. Would it be possible to explain why servlet location is repeating and how can I succesfully navigate to test.jsp via controller?

Thanks a lot for your feedback in advance.

Edit1:

Thanks areus for the feedback. After modifying action on confirm.jsp, I am getting the below error. URL is not repeating anymore but it can't navigate back. 
[image]

Please find HTML code for the confirm.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Confirm Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        The value of the hobby that was sent to this page is <strong>web programming </strong>.
    <p>
    <form action="/ch2/servletController/Controller">
    <p>
        If there is any error, please click the edit button and 
            to process press the Submit button <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="hobby" value="web programming">
        <input type="submit" name="Edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the form in `Confirm.jsp` you are using a relative URL: `ch2/servletController/Controller`. The URL is relative to the location of the resource that served the request (the location in the address bar of the browser), `http://localhost:9191/SampleProject/ch/servletController/Controller`.

You should use an absolute URL on you `Confirm.jsp`, using:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ch2/servletController/Controller">
```

Comment: Thanks Areus for the feedback. I have updated form action to, <form action="${request.contextPath}/ch2/servletController/Controller"> but still I am getting the error.

Comment: What's the HTML generated? I

Comment: Hi Areus, I have added HTML code for confirm.jsp in the question.

Comment: My fault. I was thinking in JSF. In JSP there is not a `request` implicit object. You need to use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`. I will update the answer

Comment: You may have an issue also on your servlet with the `address` var you use to get the `RequestDispatcher`. You should use a leading `/` also for `test.jsp` and `Process.jsp` like you did with `/Confirm.jsp`

Comment: Thanks Areus. It does solved the issue. Have a nice day.